# JavaScript regex for at least 2 non alphabetic characters in any order

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for JavaScript regex pattern to restrict at least 2 non alphabetic characters in any order. So far I have tried this.

```
/(?=(.*[`!@#$%\^&*\-_=\+'/\.,]|[0-9])){2}/i.test('d1cdddd'); // Outputs true, should return false
/(?=(.*[`!@#$%\^&*\-_=\+'/\.,]|[0-9])){2}/i.test('@'); // Outputs true, should return false
/(?=(.*[`!@#$%\^&*\-_=\+'/\.,]|[0-9])){2}/i.test('aa@'); // Outputs true, should return false
/(?=(.*[`!@#$%\^&*\-_=\+'/\.,]|[0-9])){2}/i.test('@aaaa'); // Outputs true, should return false
/(?=(.*[`!@#$%\^&*\-_=\+'/\.,]|[0-9])){2}/i.test('xrg@aaaa'); // Outputs true, should return false
/(?=(.*[`!@#$%\^&*\-_=\+'/\.,]|[0-9])){2}/i.test('xrg4aaaa'); // Outputs true, should return false
```

> The string can contain alphabets and (at least 2 numbers) or (at least
>   2 special characters) or (at least 1 number and at least 1 special
>   character) in any order

Example of valid cases/strings:

1. `1sfdfsd2`
2. `asd12`
3. `3asd@df`
4. `22`
5. `@^`
6. `2*`
7. `*sff)f`
8. `.(()2fd`

Comment: `/[^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[^a-zA-Z]/`?

Comment: Do you mean ^(?=(?:.*[`!@#$%^&*\-_=+'/.,]){2}) see https://regex101.com/r/Sj4Wb3/1

Comment: Try using alternations and a lookahead `^(?=[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z])(?:[A-Za-z]*[0-9][A-Za-z]*[0-9][A-Za-z]*|[A-Za-z]*[`!@#$%^&*\-_=+'/.,][A-Za-z]*[`!@#$%^&*\-_=+'/.,][A-Za-z]*|[A-Za-z]*[0-9][A-Za-z]*[`!@#$%^&*\-_=+'/.,][A-Za-z]*|[A-Za-z]*[`!@#$%^&*\-_=+'/.,][A-Za-z]*[0-9][A-Za-z]*)$` https://regex101.com/r/hDEGSk/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird case 4, 5, 6, 7 does not matches

Comment: @MahavirMunot Then you can omit the lookahead to assert a char a-zA-Z and add `()` to the character class. See https://regex101.com/r/1SoBLG/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple Regex:

```
^.*[\d$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-].*[\d$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-].*$
```

You can add or remove any special characters you want inside the brackets

Test it: https://regex101.com/r/rkjPbb/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and ranges to specify which characters you  want to allow to match.

If you don't want to allow whitespaces or other not specified characters you could use:

Note that the range `#-/` matches from [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) char 35 - 47 and `:->` matches from ASCII char 58 - 62.

```
^[!#-/:->@^_|a-zA-Z\d]*[!#-/:->@^_|\d][!#-/:->@^_|a-zA-Z\d]*[!#-/:->@^_|\d][!#-/:->@^_|a-zA-Z\d]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[!#-/:->@^_|a-zA-Z\d]*` Match 0+ times the allowed chars
- `[!#-/:->@^_|\d]` Match a special char or digit
- `[!#-/:->@^_|a-zA-Z\d]*` Match 0+ times the allowed chars
- `[!#-/:->@^_|\d]` Match a special char or digit
- `[!#-/:->@^_|a-zA-Z\d]*` Match 0+ times the allowed chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ilvA2s/1)

Comment: @theforuthbird Can you review it again, it does not match 8th case in the examples

Comment: @MahavirMunot Yes, but that is because you are extending the examples. For the 8th example this part `or (2 special characters)` is not valid anymore because now there are 4.

Comment: What is exactly the logic of `The string can contain alphabets and (2 numbers) or (2 special characters) or (1 number and 1 special character) in any order`. Exact 2 numbers, at least 2 numbers, exact 2 special chars, at least 2 special chars or 1 exact 1 special char and 1 digit or at least?

Comment: The string can contain alphabets and (at least 2 numbers) or (at least 2 special characters) or (at least 1 number and at least 1 special character) in any order. My bad, I was not clear